# When trying to implement tensorflow lite model in Android studio I am getting an incompatible data types error

Tags: java, python, android-studio, tensorflow, keras

I built a simple tensorflow multi-class classification model in python using keras sequential. And I am now trying to run that model in Android studio but I get the following error in Android studio.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite tensor with type INT64 and a Java object of type [[F (which is compatible with the TensorFlowLite type FLOAT32).
```

I will first paste the google colab notebook code that I used to create the model. Essentially there are two input variables (2 integers) and the model then classifies the probability of getting 171 different classes based on those 2 input variables. I will then include the java code used in android studio to try and run the tflite model.

This is the python code used to build the classification model

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data_to_load['species_by_location_v4.csv']))

# CREATE X ARRAY
# This is the array containing the explanatory variables (in this case pentad and month)

loc_array = df.iloc[:, 1:3]
print(loc_array)

# create y array (classes to be predicted)

label_array = df.iloc[:, 4]

# get number of distinct classes and convert y array to consecutive integers from 0 to 170 (y_true)

raw_y_true = label_array
mapping_to_numbers = {}
y_true = np.zeros((len(raw_y_true)))
for i, raw_label in enumerate(raw_y_true):
    if raw_label not in mapping_to_numbers:
        mapping_to_numbers[raw_label] = len(mapping_to_numbers)
    y_true[i] = mapping_to_numbers[raw_label]
print(y_true)
# [0. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2.]
print(mapping_to_numbers)

# get number of distinct classes

num_classes = len(mapping_to_numbers)
print(num_classes)


# create simple model

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])

# compile model

model.compile(
    optimizer = 'adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# train model

history = model.fit(loc_array, y_true, epochs=500, verbose=False)
print('finished')

# create labels file

labels = '\n'.join(mapping_to_numbers.keys())

with open('labels_locmth.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(labels)

!cat labels.txt

# convert to tflite

saved_model_dir = 'save/fine_tuning'
tf.saved_model.save(model, saved_model_dir)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('model_locmth.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

In python I can use the following code to run a prediction using the model. It simply requires the 2 integer values as input variables, in this case 63669 and 2.

```
temp = {'pentad_unique_key': [63669], 'mth': [2] }
test_x = pd.DataFrame(temp, columns = ['pentad_unique_key', 'mth'])
result = model.predict(test_x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)
```

Now in Android studio I use the following code to try and run the model. I'm trying to pass it the same two integers as I did in the python code above. Its on the final line here that I get the error above.

```
float[][] inputVal = new float[1][2];
inputVal[0][0] = 63669;
inputVal[0][1] = 2;

float[][] outputs = new float[1][171];

tflite.run(inputVal, outputs);
```

This is how I construct the tflite object

```
try{
   tflite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile());
   labelList = loadLabelList();
} catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the loadModelFile method

```
private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {

    // Open the model using an input stream and memory map it to load
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = this.getAssets().openFd("model_locmth.tflite");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);

}
```

I have a feeling the problem is something to do with the inputVal array?

Comment: I think there is a mismatch in dtype. what is the dtype of `y_true`.  Can you share the data (if it is not private), I will try to build one and test it. If it is private, make a toy data and share.

Comment: Hi Vishnuvardhan. Thank you so much for the response. I have no problem sharing the data and the full colab python code. What is the best way to share the data? Can I do it through this site? Or do you want to give me an email address?

Comment: This is the shape of y_true `tf.Tensor([1344], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)`

Comment: share a google drive link here. When I click to download, you will get a notification saying that vishnuvardhanj requested access? Then you can give access to me.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GK6S1laKLfSbgRGLl8jjYXonUDZ-wuQB

Comment: Please try that link and let me know if it doesnt work. It should link you to a folder on google drive which consists of the csv file containing the data (species_by_location_v4.csv) and a google colab file used to create the tensorflow lite model (model_build.ipynb) and then I have also included the java file from my android studio where I am trying to run the tensorflow lite model. Thank you so much again for lending a hand and please excuse any beginner code you might see.

Comment: I was able to download. I will check. Regarding "beginner" comment, everyone (including great people) was a beginner at some point. Another point is the above grive link is accessible to anyone who has link. Just to keep yourself safe, don't allow everyone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213034/discussion-between-jon-and-vishnuvardhan-janapati).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, I think the issue is with the input dtype of `y_true`.
when you create `y_true` as

```
y_true = np.zeros((len(raw_y_true)))
```

it will show the dtype as np.int64 as that was default dtype.
tflite models can work with float32 (not int64 or float64) as was mentioned in the error
so you need to define y_true as

```
y_true = np.zeros((len(raw_y_true)),dtype=np.float32)
```

So, I changed only the above line in the following section of the code

```
label_array = df.iloc[:, 4]

raw_y_true = label_array
mapping_to_numbers = {}
y_true = np.zeros((len(raw_y_true)),dtype=np.float32)
for i, raw_label in enumerate(raw_y_true):
    if raw_label not in mapping_to_numbers:
        mapping_to_numbers[raw_label] = len(mapping_to_numbers)
    y_true[i] = mapping_to_numbers[raw_label]
print(y_true)
# [0. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2.]
print(mapping_to_numbers)

print(np.argmax(result)) # 122
```

One suggestion is to use tensorflow operations in the code where ever it is possible. For example, instead of using `np.zeros`, use `tf.zeros` etc.

Earlier I had similar error for a simple model where I was using float64. Full code of that model and error you can see [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Keras_Model_2_TFLite.ipynb). Hope it helps.

Comment: Your advice above has led me to a model that is now working. The key, as you said, is to ensure that the data (X and Y data) used to train the model are tensors of type float32. I used the following code to get the data in the correct format: `loc_tensor=tf.convert_to_tensor(loc_array, dtype=tf.float32)` for the input data and `y_tensor=tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true, dtype=tf.float32)` for the Y data (labels). Thank you so much for your time and help on this. I've learnt alot and I really appreciate it.

Comment: I am happy that it helped you.